# What steps do you need to take to transition from pc game development to vr game development?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, game-development, virtual-reality

Im being hesitant to either dive straight into learning vr development or first start with 2d/3d games for pc or mobile.

Once you learn 2d/3d game development with unity, what steps do you need to take to move on to VR game development? would the two types of game development have a lot in common? or would it be two very different areas?

Answer (score 2):

I myself do not have any experience in VR development but I can say that diving straight into VR development might be a little overwhelming if you do not have any experience in game development or any experience in Unity. I suggest that you first follow some tutorials on YouTube to make a simple 2D pc game so you can get more comfortable using Unity and its features.

Transfering to VR from 2D shouldn't be that hard if you are starting to get more familiar with Unity. There are plenty of tutorials on YouTube relating to VR deveploment

Great YouTube channel for learning Unitys basic features is [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/user/brackeys). They have made some great tutorials that helped me in the beginning of my game deveploment journey.